# Gui Torrent Creator with WebSeeding

Tags: bittorrent

I am looking for Torrent Creator with Web seeding ability. Please tell me if there are any available to me under Ubuntu or any other place.

Comment: Which torrent client do you use?

Comment: transmission torrent. And ttorrent on Android

Answer (score 1):

Clients like Transmission and Deluge are capable of creating torrents. Once the torrent file is created, it needs to be uploaded to your favorite torrent site for seeding( i.e. isohunt.com). Usually, instructions are provided on the front page of the site to get your torrent file uploaded.

Comment: isoHunt is an indexing search engine for torrents. Although one can *download* copies of `.torrent` files from isoHunt.com, it is not a tracker, and one cannot *upload* a torrent to it. See [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isohunt) for details. You are on to something by suggesting isoHunt, though, in that one reasonable way to find good trackers is to enter a variety of search queries into isoHunt and see which trackers are tracking what appear to be the most useful results.

Answer (score 1):

dottorrent-gui supports this: https://github.com/kz26/dottorrent-gui

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be suffering from a misconception. Torrent clients/creators don't have Web Seeding capability. Webseeding is done with an HTTP or FTP server. The client may or may not be capable of downloading from a webseed. For a further understanding you may wish to review [What is "web seed"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313107/what-is-web-seed) and http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0019.html

Sources:

http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0019.html

[What is "web seed"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313107/what-is-web-seed)

Answer (score 0):

Most torrent programs have the ability to create a torrent in the menu, my personal favourite is qBittorrent for it's simplicity and sheer speed of use...

http://www.techsupportalert.com/qbittorrent-help-main-window

Comment: can you check if it has webseed function http://bittorrentwebseeds.blogspot.com/

Comment: @BigSack you could do that yourself

Comment: Deluge also has a support of webseed

Answer (score -2):

## [Transmission](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/transmission/)

Transmission is the default torrent client in Ubuntu. To create a new torrent, go to file menu and choose the new option (Or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>).

[image: screenshot of new torrent screen]

Like most torrent clients, it also supports seeding.

Comment: are you aware of what is webseeding?

Comment: I wasn't aware of webseeding, but I looked into it, and it seems Transmission does support it. See https://trac.transmissionbt.com/ticket/3519 for more details.

Comment: but how to create web seeded torrent. I suppose it supports downloading web seeded torrents not creating web seeded torrents