# File server that works like samba but over internet? :)

Tags: 14.04, server, samba, remote, file-server

Is there any alternative file-server program because i want to edit my files on the server so i don't have to download all files to my computer before i can edit them. I'm using samba locally it works just like i wanted.

Comment: How about samba? You would have to redirect the ports. How to do that depends on your setup, and I will probably not be much of a help.

Comment: I suggest that you review http://askubuntu.com/questions/126850/how-do-i-use-ubuntu-server-as-file-server which covers numerous methods. Although I personally would use NFS

Comment: @ElderGeek Considering (s)he already has set up a samba server, I think the problem is portforwarding  and the necessary security which is not covered by the answer you linked to.

Comment: @Bruni Port Forwarding is a router configuration issue and likely would be considered outside the scope of acceptable questions here although some answers regarding that can likely be found at http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/port-forwarding

Comment: Ive tried to portforward samba several times without success so im trying to get alternative way now. PS. I know how to forward ports.

Answer (score 2):

One solution to this is the WebDav protocol, which runs over http (or preferably https).
I have never had the need to set this up myself, but this video a video showing how to configure the server side on Ubuntu 10.04 looks useful... [Set Up WebDAV With Apache2 On Ubuntu 14.04 Server](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AaSA92DaK9g) thats on You Tube.

Comment: Im confused :D like so i can just install webdav and access my samba files ? :)

Comment: @smthng WebDav works like Samba but it only uses one network port so port forwarding should be a lot simpler. If you are connecting from a Windows client, then you will need some additional software to map a drive. Microsoft Office can open WebDav files without mapping a drive though. There are some suggestions for Windows clients on [this page](https://barracudadrive.com/tutorials/mapping_windows_drive.lsp).

Comment: So WebDav is actually the filesharing program or you USE webdav to connect samba ?

Comment: @smthng WebDav is a way of sharing files. It is like Samba, but does not require Samba at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the traditional [FTP(S)](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/ftp-server.html) - see FTPS part, [SFTP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420652/how-to-setup-a-restricted-sftp-server-on-ubuntu), or even [Apache Directory Index](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html) ([example](http://screenshots.getdeb.net/dists/trusty-getdeb/)). What are your needs according to the speed, data size, etc...?
Also I can imagine a [torrent client on the server, with web seed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313107/what-is-web-seed), if you need massive file sharing.

Quick solution is a [VPN server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119534/easiest-way-to-setup-ubuntu-as-a-vpn-server), if you have public IP. Combine with [DynDNS service](http://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/installing-the-linux-dynamic-update-client-on-ubuntu/) and you get what you need.

Ps. you can not avoid port opening, just in case of a torrent client, with an internet-wide accessible private/public tracker. Consider using [Magnet links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet_URI_scheme), [open trackers](https://www.google.com/#q=open%20torrent%20trackers), [DHT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mainline_DHT)!

If you need future assistance, ask in comments!